# Yet another JS newbie question

Tags: javascript

I just want to have a function `VK.Share.Count(param1,param2)` and property `VK.Share.WorkUrl`.

`VK.Share.WorkUrl` must be available from `VK.Share.Count` function. What is best way to do it? Can i just write:

```
VK.Share.Count = function(a,b) {
   //blablablablablalbalblablal
   VK.Share.WorkUrl = "sdfgfgadf";
}

VK.Share.WorkUrl = "lalalala";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var vk={
 share:{ 
           count:function(){},
           WorkUrl:"lalala"
       }
};
```

**or**

```
var vk={}
vk.share={};
vk.share.count=function(){
}
vk.share.WorkUrl="lalal";
```

Answer (score 1):

You example will work and this will also work, if you are always calling the Count function like this `VK.Share.Count();`

```
VK.Share.Count = function(a,b) { this.WorkUrl = "foobar"; }
VK.Share.WorkUrl = "123";
```